# Populate an App Engine NDB entity with data from WTForms

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-datastore, wtforms

I'm looking for a more elegant way to populate an App Engine Datastore entity from a WTForms model without assigning each property one at a time.

I remember seeing something similar done with `getattr()`.

WTForm model for the edit profile page, like this:

```
class EditProfile(Form):
    first_name = StringField('First Name')
    last_name = StringField('Last Name')
    [...]
```

NDB model for users:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    first_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    last_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    [...]
```

Note: all property names of both models identical.

Request handler for the edit profile page:

```
@app.route('/edit_profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_profile():
    form = EditProfile()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.get_by_id(session.get('user_id'))

            ???

            user.put()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [populate_obj](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj) method.

> Populates the attributes of the passed obj with data from the form’s
>   fields.

```
form.populate_obj(user)
user.put()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like...:

```
for field in dir(form):
    if field.startswith('_'): continue  # skip private stuff
    if not user.hasattr(field): continue  # skip non-corresponding stuff
    value = getattr(form, field)
    setattr(user, field, value)
```

There may be subtleties e.g about types (requiring type conversion for certain fields) or even fancier ones (maybe we need to work with `User.hasattr`, i.e, on the class, not the instance), but this is a generally good starting point for transcribing equally-named, compatibly-typed fields between two different kinds of class instances.

Comment: This _almost_ worked. I'm using Dmitry's answer but just for the record, a couple things: change value to value.data. The main issue was user.hasattr raised Attribute error. Tried to get around that with `if not getattr(user.__class__, field): continue` and that raised `type object 'User' has no attribute 'Meta'`